# Known issues migrating Excel 2007 models to Windows 7

Tags: excel, windows-7, migration

I work on a business modelling team, using mainly Excel 2007. If it's complicated and it gets done in Excel, we've done it. Which is why I'm nervous about my team's plan to upgrade our OS to Windows 7. I wanted to know if there are any known issues when migrating from XP to Windows 7, but staying on the same version of Excel. I know that it seems like it shouldn't matter, but I'm looking for an answer from someone who has done this with fairly intricate Excel models.

Comment: Some examples of things about which I am nervous: using VBA to save files, using web-browser elements in forms and having UAC confirmations pop up in the middle of previously functional macros. Thanks.

Comment: do plan on migrating to win7 32 bit or 64 bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you will get a list of known issues as there could be a multitude of potential issues that are specific to particular libraries and how your code interacts with that library.

If you're using identical Excel 2007 versions (32-bit/64-bit) and code is restricted to only Excel's object model you should generally be ok (although charting I've always found a little suspect on 2007).

If you're using external libraries set in references then I would assume further development will be required - however, it may not!

If development is required, it could involve something simple such as early binding to specific libraries or downloading specific libraries if they're still available. You may have to re-write some code to handle version changes. For example, if you use library MSXML then a machine may have one or more of MSXML3.0 - 6.0 depending upon OS/Office installed.

Microsoft do list object model changes [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee836187.aspx#XL14DevRef_ChangesSince2007) but I don't think this is applicable in your case. Unfortunately, I don't know of any standard resources for external libraries. You will have to test.

Comment: -1 Kind of missed the point - question is about keeping Excel 2007 and migrating OS from XP to Win7

Comment: @Chris - that's exactly what I had in mind when answering the question.

Comment: Thanks for your response, makes a lot of sense, I was just trying to get a leg up on the testing by getting my head around the _types_ of things which might cause issues. Your answer has helped, I'll accept it if no definitive ones come through.